# HtmlAgilityPack How to Select Last Child in Wildcard Search

Tags: html, powershell, html-agility-pack

In this question, assume the starting node preceding the first dot is .DocumentNode, type HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument

`.SelectSingleNode("*[contains(.,'Year Interior:')]")`

Results in:

InnerHtml            : `<table width="822" height="173" class="diy-section-content-table adSpecView-section-content-body-container" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td class="diy-section-content-table-td diy-template-column" valign="top"><ul><li><strong>Year Interior:</strong>2007</li><li>Good Condition</li></ul></td></tr></tbody>`

I need the result to be only the last child containing "Year Interior:":

`<li><strong>Year Interior:</strong>2007</li>`

The Html I'm searching is inconsistent.  "Year Interior:" may be in `<li>,<span>,<td>,<div>, etc.`, which is why I cannot be more explicit in the search.

How could something like `.SelectSingleNode("*[contains(.,'Year Interior:')]")` return only the last child containing "Year Interior:" and not the container element?

Of course, I cannot do this, yet it shows the result I need:
`.SelectSingleNode("*/*/*/*/*/*/*[contains(.,'Year Interior:')]")`

Needed Result : InnerHtml: `<strong>Year Interior:</strong> 2007`

UPDATE:
Trying the following is long-winded and close to working except it catches formatting tags, like `<strong>` and `<em>`:

`.Descendants() | Where-Object {$_.InnerHtml -like "*Year Interior:*" -and $_.HasChildNodes -eq $false}).ParentNode`

In this case, the first parent node is the strong tag, so the code will become more unwieldy to check if it's a formatting tag.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(_ => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_.InnerText) && _.InnerText.Trim().Equals("Year Interior:"));
```

Comment: I updated the question based on your proposed answer, filtering Descendants.  It's closer.

Comment: If you don't want you can add this condition to Where statement `&& _.Name.Equals(HtmlNodeType.Text)`